# Visual studio 2012 and Qt4.8.5 : How to see QString contents in debug mode.

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, qt4.8

I use visual studio 2012 and Qt4.8.5, unfortunately I can not see the QString text variable when I work in debug mode. Is someone has a tip allow it ? Qt4.8.5 plug-in doesn't exist for VS2012.

Thank a lot

Xavier

Answer (score 26):

There is a quick and explicit solution (MSVC native, no need for plugins nor setting up .dat files),  [see my answer from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37293532/1150303)

Say you have `QString str` (**Qt4**), then add to the debugger watch window:

```
((str).d)->array,su
```

the appendix `,su` tells the debugger to interpret the data as unicode and null terminated string.

*Note*: For a **Qt5** `QString str` it could be

```
(char*)str.d + str.d->offset,su
```

Comment: getting: -var-create: unable to create variable object

Comment: thank you, option for Qt5((char*)str.d + str.d->offset,su) helped me)

Answer (score 8):

the **autoexp.dat** is not used unless you set the Debugger options to "*Enable native Edit and Continue*"

here is my natvis implementation of the QString for 4.8.5 (expands only the first 25 chars)

```
<Type Name="QString">
    <DisplayString>"{d->data,sub}"</DisplayString>
    <StringView>d->data,sub</StringView>
    <Expand>
        <Item Condition="d->size &gt;= 0" Name="[size]">d->size</Item>
        <Item Condition="d->size &gt; 0" Name="[referenced]">d->ref._q_value</Item>
        <ArrayItems Condition="d->size&lt;=25">
            <Size>d->size</Size>
            <ValuePointer>d->data,c</ValuePointer>
        </ArrayItems>
        <ArrayItems Condition="d->size&gt;25">
            <Size>25</Size>
            <ValuePointer>d->data,c</ValuePointer>
        </ArrayItems>
        <Item Condition="d->size&gt;25" Name="...">d->size - 25</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>
```

at least the qt4.natvis can coexist with the qt5.natvis as one or the other fails to load correctly...

Comment: Great ! the debugger options set to "Enable native Edit and Continue" and the natvis file work ! Thank.

Comment: VS2015 the autoexp.dat ist still a INI like file .... No XML at all there ... What I am missing?

Answer (score 6):

For Visual 2015, 2017 and 2019,

just install the dedicated Qt plugin for Visual.

Download it from [here](https://download.qt.io/development_releases/vsaddin/2.5.0/)

Answer (score 3):

For me, in Qt5 and Visual Studio 2012, i just did this:

Project options -> debugging -> Debugger type -> Set it **from Auto to Mixed**.

Not the strings are displayed in the watch.

Comment: Hi, It is not in the project's properties. Go to Tools menu -> options -> debugging -> Edit and Continue. **Check Native Edit and continue**.

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2015...

Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Check "Use Native Compatibility Mode"

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked for QString qStr :

p qStr.toStdString();

I executed this in command line (available in visual studio), worked in gdb and lldb.