# Qt5 Visual Studio 2012 Add-In does not allow debugging into QStack/QVector

Tags: visual-studio-2012, qt5, debuggervisualizer, qvector

I'm using the newest Add-In (1.2.3) but when I try to view the values inside a QVector (Qt 5.3.2) it says 0 (error). It was still working in Qt 4.8.4.
Does anyone have a working visualizer for VS2012?

The code for the autoexp.dat in the [gitorious repository](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/vstools/source/430323c448a7469c9f9cbc18c22fbab40d8c745d:tools/Qt4EEAddin/autoexp.dat-visualizer2012#L636) still says "4.6":

```
; QVector, QStack
; By default, this visualizer supports only Qt 4.6.x. ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use qt5 with Visual Studio Add-In you don't need the autoexp.dat any longer. Make sure to disable debugger option "Enable native Edit and Continue"  (menu -> options -> debugging -> Edit and Continue) to use the xml-based  native vis definitions in [qt5.natvis] (https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/vstools/source/803678eef900077c5047afc2ab2999f7bf08f6db:tools/Qt4EEAddin/qt5.natvis)

This question ([Visual studio 2012 and Qt4.8.5 : How to see QString contents in debug mode.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324166/visual-studio-2012-and-qt4-8-5-how-to-see-qstring-contents-in-debug-mode)) has qt4 title, but is later on related to qt5 with visual studio 2012 and might be interesting for you as well.