# Value for a QString showing as byte array in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, debugging, qstring

```
QString str = "hello";
```

When I debug the code in Visual Studio 2010 and add a watch to `str`, I'm unable to get the data it contains as a string. The watch shows only the internal byte array.

How can I get the value of a `QString` as a text string, rather than a byte array?

I tried in VS2008 as well, and i was getting the value as text string.

Comment: Post a screenshot of what the variable is looking in the debugger. Also see these similar questions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324166/visual-studio-2012-and-qt4-8-5-how-to-see-qstring-contents-in-debug-mode and http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/33200-QString-is-not-shown-properly-in-Watch-%28Qt-Add-in-1-1-5-for-Visual-Studio-2008%29. Maybe the solutions there will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need Qt Visual Studio Add-in or write your own debugger type visualizer:

http://wiki.qt.io/IDE-debug-helpers

Comment: i'm able to compile and debug successfully. The issue is QString is not displayed as text string. FYI, i have used the VS add-in as well.

Comment: Do you find Qt types in `c:\program files(x86)\<visual studio>\common7\packages\debugger\autoexp.dat`?

Comment: Take one from https://github.com/qtproject/qt-labs-vstools/tree/master/tools/Qt4EEAddin

Comment: svlasov: this link is dead.

Comment: David Faure: after some googling https://github.com/JackyDing/Qt4VSAddin/tree/master/tools/Qt4EEAddin