# Display QString (Qt5) content in Visual Studio 2013 debugging?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013, qt5

I used to google a lot about it.

- I enabled Debugging -> Edit and Continue in Native Only options
- I was trying to add Visualizers to `Visual Studio 2013\Visualizers`
- vstools project on codeplex is not for 2013 seems like

but so far nothing helps...

Comment: have you tried the [Visual Studio Add-in](http://wiki.qt.io/QtVSAddin)? also have a look at https://wiki.qt.io/IDE-debug-helpers#MS_Visual_Studio_2013

Comment: @m.s.yes, seems like 2010 is last supported version there http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-labs/vstools.git/tree/Qt4VS2003/createUserFiles.pl

Comment: some more links, that should help: http://forum.qt.io/topic/34189/qt-in-visual-studio-2013/2 and http://download.qt.io/official_releases/vsaddin/qt-vs-addin-1.2.4-opensource.exe.mirrorlist

Comment: @m.s. I installed it, added qt to it but still I can't see QString content...

Comment: I recommend using this pre-built addon: [VS 2013 addin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheQtCompany.QtVisualStudioTools)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to see `QString` content by disabling `Debugging -> Edit and Continue`

not sure if there could be better solutions

Comment: does this also work without the Qt Visual Studio Add-in?

Comment: @m.s. I don't know but I think so

Comment: This does not work without the add-in (tested in VS 2013)

Answer (score 9):

There is an explicit, native MSVC solution without the use of plugins etc.:  [see my answer from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37293532/1150303)

Say you have `QString str`, then add to the debugger session *watch window*:

**Qt4**:

```
((str).d)->array,su
```

for **Qt5** it's slightly more complicated:

```
(char*)str.d + str.d->offset,su
```

Answer (score 1):

I search this problem's answer for a long time, and final success saw the QString content by try check/uncheck mentioned options. Hope can help others.

[image: Screenshot: display qstring content]

1. Install **qt-vs-addin-msvc2013-2.0.0-beta.vsix**
2. Uncheck TOOLS->Debugging->Edit and Continue->Enable native Edit and Continue
   [image: Screenshot: Uncheck TOOLS->Debugging->Edit and Continue->Enable native Edit and Continue]

Comment: Thank you for supplying the full path to the "Enable native Edit and Continue" setting and screenshot. That helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a while back but if relevant, for VS 2013 then go to

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers"
```

and add Code from below link in a text file and name it qt5.natvis. 
For VS 2019 the location would be:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers"
```

Hope this helps.

[pastebin code for seeing qt variables in visual studio](https://pastebin.com/PdwCefS2)

Comment: Would all the QVariant checks in that file slow down the debug session?